# Display Outlook Web App email in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to display outlook email to SharePoint page.

I have tried to display outlook email to Page viewer web-part but getting error

[image]

is there any way to achieve it. please help me out

**Updated** : 
I have followed below link 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Working-with-Outlook-Web-Access-Web-Parts-24589931-15ac-4703-92c9-519a11542404?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

In this site it is given that

Under Page Viewer on the tool pane, make sure Web Page is selected. In the Link field, type the URL for the Outlook Web App. Note that the Outlook URL must include the parameter exsvurl=1. For example, the Outlook URL typically resembles the following: https://www.outlook.com/owa/?exsvurl=1&cmd=contents&part=1&fpath=inbox&realm=contoso.onmicrosoft.com , where the SharePoint Online realm “contoso.onmicrosoft.com” represents the URL you used when you signed up for your Office 365 subscription.

so i have given below url

`https://outlook.office.com/owa/#exsvurl=1&cmd=contents&part=1&fpath=inbox&realm=outlook.office.com`

but still i get the same error "There is a problem connecting securely to this website"

Comment: Can you add the site to trusted site and check ?

Answer (score 3):

Follow Below Steps to **Add an Outlook Web Access Web Part to a page**

1. From a page, in the ribbon, click the **Page** tab, and then click the **Edit Page** command.
2. Click on the page where you want to add a Web Part, click the **Insert** tab, and then click **Web Part**.
3. Under **Categories**, click **Outlook Web App**.
4. Under **Web Parts**, select the Outlook Web Access Web Part that you want to add to the page, and then click **Add**.
5. On the page, point to the Web Part, click the down arrow, and then click **Edit Web Part**.
6. In the **Mail Configuration** section of the tool pane, type the URL for your Outlook Web Access server in the **Mail server address** box. **For example, https://mail.contoso.com**
7. In **Mailbox**, type your email address, such as connie@contoso.com.
8. Configure the other options for the Web Part as you prefer.
9. Click **OK** to save your settings and exit the tool pane, or click **Apply** to see your changes without closing the tool pane..
10. When you have finished editing the page, click the **Page** tab, and then click **Stop Editing**.

**Else**

Please try below mentioned link.

[Outlook Web App in SharePoint Online](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/lystavlen/2012/05/29/outlook-web-app-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: I can not see any `Outlook Web App` under Category while adding webpart.
is there any setting require to enable Outlook web app?

Comment: I think your approach is for SharePoint onperm. I am looking in to Office 365.

Comment: Kindly check the URL provided in the answer

Comment: Same link i have tried using page viewer, but on getting error "There is a problem connecting securely yo this website"

Comment: Are you trying with **https** or **http**?

Comment: I am trying with https

Answer (score 2):

It will help you :

1-From a page, in the ribbon, click the Page tab, and then click the Edit Page command.

NOTE:  If the Edit Page command is disabled, you may not have the permissions to edit the page. Contact your administrator.

2-Click on the page where you want to add a Web Part, click the Insert tab, and then click More Web Parts.

3-Under All Categories, click Media and Content.

4-Click the Page Viewer Web Part, and then click Add.

5-On the page, point to the Page Viewer Web Part, click the down arrow, and then click Edit Web Part.

6-Under Page Viewer on the tool pane, make sure Web Page is selected. In the Link field, type the URL for the Outlook Web App. Note that the Outlook URL must include the parameter exsvurl=1. For example, the Outlook URL typically resembles the following: https://www.outlook.com/owa/?exsvurl=1&cmd=contents&part=1&fpath=inbox&realm=contoso.onmicrosoft.com , where the SharePoint Online realm “contoso.onmicrosoft.com” represents the URL you used when you signed up for your Office 365 subscription. For more details on defining the Outlook URL to enter in the Link field, see “Using Outlook Web App Web Parts” below.

7-You may want to adjust the height of the Web Part in the tool pane until it shows as much of the Outlook Web Access interface as you want. To do this, click Appearance under Should the Web Part have a fixed height?, click Yes, and then type the number of pixels, such as 500.

8-Click OK to save your settings and exit the tool pane, or click Apply to see your changes without closing the tool pane.

9-When you have finished editing the page, click the Page tab, and then click Save & Close.

For additional tips on defining an Outlook URL, such as parameters you can add to show specific pages or views, see Using Outlook Web App Web Parts on Microsoft TechNet.

Look at this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Working-with-Outlook-Web-Access-Web-Parts-24589931-15ac-4703-92c9-519a11542404

Comment: Please check updated question i have followed the same link but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your realm-link this is supposed to be your tenant-name like `abcconsulting.onmicrosoft.com`.

And use URL for Page viewer like given below:

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa/#exsvurl=1&cmd=contents&part=1&fpath=inbox&realm=<tenantid>.onmicrosoft.com
```